# Get NFS client IP address in a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, nfs

I'm working on a kernel module to track the operations performed by NFS clients on my server.
I can intercept the file operations using a hacky way (hijacking the vfs layer) but I can't retrieve the IP address of the client.

Is there any information that might be stored in the `current` task that I can use to obtain the IP address of the NFS client performing an operation?

I know from digging into the source code that nfsd stores a `struct nfsd_net` in the `struct super_block`'s `s_fs_info` field, but I can only retrieve it as a `struct net` pointer. And in nfsd's implementation `net_generic` method is being used to get the `struct nfsd_net` pointer (using `nfsd_net_id` which is the `pernet_operations`'s `id`).

Can I obtain this id somehow? and if yes, can I use the `struct nfsd_net` in my kernel module? Is it defined somewhere other than the `fs/nfsd/netns.h`?

**Edit**

I'm using [this approach](http://turbochaos.blogspot.com/2013/10/writing-linux-rootkits-201-23.html) to hijack the open function. I'm writing this for kernel version 4.15.0. Here's the code of the kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kobject.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/cred.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/preempt.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/xattr.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

#if defined(__i386__)
    #define POFF 1
    #define CSIZE 6
    // push address, addr, ret
    char *jmp_code="\x68\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc3";
    typedef unsigned int PSIZE;
#else
    #define POFF 2
    #define CSIZE 12
    // mov address to register rax, jmp rax. for normal x64 convention
    char *jmp_code="\x48\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xe0";
    typedef unsigned long PSIZE;
#endif

DEFINE_SPINLOCK(root_open_lock);

int (*orig_root_open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
void *orig_root_open_code;

void hook(void *src_func,void *dst_addr){
  barrier();
  write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
  memcpy(src_func,jmp_code,CSIZE);
  *(PSIZE *)&(((unsigned char*)src_func)[POFF])=(PSIZE)dst_addr;
  write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);
  barrier();
}

void save_and_hook(void **p_reserve,void *src_func,void *dst_addr){
  barrier();
  write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
  *p_reserve=kmalloc(CSIZE,GFP_KERNEL);
  // save origin code
  memcpy(*p_reserve,src_func,CSIZE);
  hook(src_func,dst_addr);
  write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);
  barrier();
}

void fix(void **p_reserve,void *src_func){
  barrier();
  write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
  memcpy(src_func,*p_reserve,CSIZE);
  write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);
  barrier();
}

int fake_root_open(struct inode *x, struct file *fp)
{
  int ret;

  printk("vfshijack: hijacked open\n"); // I need to find the client ip here.

  barrier();
  spin_lock(&root_open_lock);
  fix(&orig_root_open_code, orig_root_open);
  ret = orig_root_open(x, fp);
  hook(orig_root_open, fake_root_open);
  spin_unlock(&root_open_lock);
  barrier();
  return ret;
}

int vfs_init(void)
{
  struct file *fp = filp_open("/", O_DIRECTORY|O_RDONLY, 0);
  if (IS_ERR(fp))
    return -1;

  orig_root_open = fp->f_op->open;
  if(orig_root_open)
  {
    save_and_hook(&orig_root_open_code, orig_root_open, fake_root_open);
  }

  filp_close(fp, NULL);

  printk("vfshijack: vfshijack loaded\n");
  return 0;
}

void vfs_exit(void)
{
  if(orig_root_open)
  {
    fix(&orig_root_open_code, orig_root_open);
  }
  printk("vfshijack: vfshijack unloaded\n");
}

module_init(vfs_init);
module_exit(vfs_exit);
```

Comment: Hello Mohamed. Could you please post online current version sources of your module and point the kernel version? It can be hard to understand exact point of hijacking. Also: using some tracing solutions (like perf trace or ftrace or lttng) may be alternative for module for your task. And could you explain a bit what is your task?

Comment: Hi osgx, I have updated the question and added the source code of the kernel module. I'm working on a proof of concept module that I can use to gather statistics about my NFS server; simply, which clients are accessing which files. These statistics can then be passed to a user-space daemon which will maybe forward them to my email address or something.

Comment: There was examples of `snoop` tool usage to trace nfs packets Solaris. Wiki https://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/NetworkTracing lists tcp dumping (`tcpdump`) as debugging option. With `perf`/`ftrace`/`trace-cmd`/stap? linux tools you can access  some tracepoints in nfs/nfsd module - `modprobe nfsd; modprobe nfs; perf list tracepoint|grep nfs`. Some patches of nfs tracepoints adding: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9913521/. It should be easier to use kernel tracing tools with predefined tracepoints than injecting/hooking custom shellcodes into kernel binary from hackish kernel module.

Comment: Looks good, but what if I want to deny an operation for specific clients? I don't think I can do that with tracing, can I? Sorry that was not clear in my post.

Comment: If you want to limit operations for clients of nfsd it will be better to have some custom (source) code somewhere, not binary hooks. You can try to create some firewall (proxy) in network path between client and server (like it was with snoop and tcpdump to trace operation), or rewrite source code of nfsd or use third-party user-space nfs daemon like [nfs-ganesha](https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki). Stap (systemtap) or eBPF with custom probe or some nfsd+audit combination may work too but it is more complicated path.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Do you have any resources for the "proxy in the network path" solution? I might wanna go with this one.

Comment: I have tried Netfilter hooks but didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Mohamed, please ask separate question about nfs firewalling with details of your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get needed information from linux kernel tracing tools without hooking kernel binary with some custom assembly. There are `perf`, `ftrace`, `trace-cmd` for most kernel versions, and `stap` and `lttng` for more custom versions. Some documentation to start: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/index.html "Linux Tracing Technologies"

There are several tracepoints defined in nfsd:

```
# modprobe nfsd
# modprobe nfs
# perf list tracepoint|grep nfs
# find /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events -type d|grep nfsd
# trace-cmd list -e nfsd:read_start -F
```

nfsd/read_start and nfsd/write_start tracepoints are good places to start. Both should have access to request structure `rqstp` with address [`rq_addr`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/include/linux/sunrpc/svc.h#L229) and fh pointer (but some eBPF or stap scripting may be useful)
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/nfsd/vfs.c#L1020

```
__be32 nfsd_read(struct svc_rqst *rqstp, struct svc_fh *fhp,...)

    trace_read_start(rqstp, fhp, offset, vlen);

    trace_read_opened(rqstp, fhp, offset, vlen);

    trace_read_io_done(rqstp, fhp, offset, vlen);

    trace_read_done(rqstp, fhp, offset, vlen);
```

I have no complete example of `trace-cmd` or stap usage for nfs daemon tracing.

Systemtap (`stap`) has some examples of nfsd statistics:
https://github.com/jav/systemtap/blob/master/testsuite/systemtap.examples/index.txt

```
# stap nfsd_unlink.stp -c "sleep 0.2"
The nfsdtop.stp script gathers and displays NFS lookups
```

https://github.com/larytet/SystemTap/blob/master/testsuite/systemtap.examples/network/nfsdtop.stp

Comment: Another variant of nfsd operations tracing is https://github.molgen.mpg.de/mariux64/mxtools/blob/master/nfsdtop/nfsdtop with kernel patches https://github.molgen.mpg.de/mariux64/mxtools/tree/master/nfsdtop/kernel-patches