# Kernel module to filter NFS requests

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, nfs

I'm working on a proof-of-concept kernel module to filter NFS requests based on some criteria (client IP address, type of operation performed, etc.)
I used a hacky method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423248/get-nfs-client-ip-address-in-a-kernel-module) but I couldn't retrieve the client IP address inside this method.

My current thinking is to have a Netfilter hook to intercept the network packets, parse them to identify the operations and apply the filtering there.

He're is a sample of what I'm talking about.. It's for kernel version 4.15.0

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* We're doing kernel work */
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Specifically, a module, */
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>  /* which will have params */
#include <linux/unistd.h>       /* The list of system calls */
#include <linux/dirent.h>
#include <linux/cred.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops nfin;

static unsigned int hook_func_in(void *priv,
                   struct sk_buff *skb,
                   const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *ip_header;
    struct tcphdr *tcph;
    char *data;

    eth = eth_hdr(skb);
    ip_header = ip_hdr(skb);
    tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);
    data = (char *)((unsigned char *)tcph + (tcph->doff * 4));
    /* Skip if it's not TCP packet */
    if (ip_header->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    printk("src mac %pM --- src IP addr:%pI4 --- protocol: %u\n", eth->h_source, &ip_header->saddr, ip_header->protocol);
    printk("TCP source : %hu, TCP  dest : %hu\n", ntohs(tcph->source), ntohs(tcph->dest));
    // Parse data pointer here..
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}

int init_module()
{
    nfin.hook     = hook_func_in;
    nfin.hooknum  = NF_INET_LOCAL_IN;
    nfin.pf       = PF_INET;
    nfin.priority = 0;
    nf_register_net_hook(&init_net, &nfin);
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
    nf_unregister_net_hook(&init_net, &nfin);
}
```

How can I parse the data pointer to be able to identify the type of request I'm handling? or how to parse the RPC request from the sk_buff object?

Is this the right approach to go about this task?

Comment: "How can I parse", "how to parse" - it's too broad. Be more specific. There is a bunch of NFS code in Linux kernel. Btw it's more appropriate to do `if (ip_header->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)` **before** trying to access TCP header.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to ask, is there some function that I can call that takes sk_buff and parses it to some RPC/NFS object? Or should I parse it on my own? and if so, how can I go about this? (what resources I can use, etc.) and thanks for the tip.

Comment: Mohamed, try to install SystemTap for your kernel (is it RHEL, CentOS, Debian or Ubuntu? what is `unama -a` output?). There is nfsdtop stap script for system tab which can access some internal nfs pointers https://github.com/larytet/SystemTap/blob/master/testsuite/systemtap.examples/network/nfsdtop.stp -- *The nfsdtop.stp script gathers and displays NFS lookups,* `# stap nfsd_unlink.stp -c "sleep 0.2"`. Another variant is to patch kernel sources and use https://github.molgen.mpg.de/mariux64/mxtools/blob/master/nfsdtop/nfsdtop tracing tool

Comment: It's Ubuntu `Linux ubuntu-VirtualBox 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.
I'll check out SystemTap and let you know.