# Kernel module to intercept nfs methods and return custom error code

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, nfs

I'm writing a proof-of-concept kernel module to intercept the [vfs_create](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/namei.c#L2880) method using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60423248/9195380) and return a custom error code (ECONNREFUSED, EHOSTDOWN, or even a new code -253).

When I try to create a file over NFS, the vfs_create method returns the custom code to the [nfsd_proc_create](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/nfsd/vfs.c#L1162) which checks to see if the error code is one of the predefined [nfserr_*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/nfsd/nfsproc.c#L761) codes, and returns [nfserr_io](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/nfsd/nfsproc.c#L811) (-5) instead to the NFS client.

Is there a way to bypass this and let the nfsd (and the nfs client?) return my custom error code?

Alternatively, is there a way to add an extra bit of data with the NFS requests/responses?

1. Client sends an open request to Server.
2. Client Kernel Module intercepts the request and adds a new field (e.g. 8-bit integer).
3. Server Kernel Module intercepts the request and extracts the new field and possibly add another new field to the response.
4. Client Kernel Module intercepts the response and extracts the new field.

Comment: Why not just modify nfs_errtbl?

Comment: NFS error codes are defined by the NFS protocol.  If you start defining new codes, you aren't using (standard) NFS any more.

Comment: @stark Any links on how to do that?

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand that. I'm okay with not using the standard NFS.